# Where are the keys on the Evil Spirit Club Floor 1?

Tags: persona-q

You need to get two keys to finish the first floor of the Evil Spirit Club Labyrinth. The key to the Practice Building and the Key to the North Building. What do I need to do to get these keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the Practice Room key you need to find two clues around the Labyrinth. The first clue is found at location C2 (B2 of that tile). Just get all of the dialog to receive the clue. There should be parts of a schedule mentioned. Then you need to make it to E4 (C4 of that tile). This will ask about specific parts of the schedule and the schedule will be found next to it (within the same event, there is no extra work on your part). Since you found the first clue you can just talk to Naoto and she will solve the problem for you completely. If you want to solve it yourself you can use the clue before. There is only the one. If you input the wrong answer there doesn't seem to be any penalty either. Naoto will just tell you you are wrong.

> There is a repeating pattern. The schedule is not actually a weekly schedule. It just a repeating pattern of classes. Put the classes given in order and insert the original clues in. It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out from there.

After answering the question you will receive the Practice Building Key.

After this the North Building Key is easy. You just need to make it to E6 (B3 of that tile) and face the north wall. You will find the North Building Key there.